# Is it possible to generate audio file from Hex/Binary(raw data) value in PHP?

Tags: php, file, audio, binary, hex

I want to write a small web application that converts hexadecimal data to audio files.

The data for the audio file will be in hexadecimal format like this:

```
DA1FFFF8B3AEEE2E23BBB9A2221F10400180001EF1C1E7F180F0FC0004FE067C03002FF92B924903450
E0C8D558F2475AF7232A28DF76493A54CE348B37D33F8616EE30A69EF56534D53320656E6320
```

How to do this using PHP?

Comment: _“Is it possible to do it using PHP?”_ - [Well let’s find out, shall we?](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+write+hex+data+to+file+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -1):

any data can get converted into audio ... if you synthesize a sin wave say at 500 cycles per second then iterate across your hex data and use this to modulate the audio you will hear patterns driven by the hex ... the current hex value could shift the frequency your sin loop is synthesizing

so step one could be to create a loop where you are synthesizing the raw audio wave ...  get this working to render audio then use the loop iterator index to walk through your hex data array and have the current hex value shift the parms you are using when synthesizing the sin wave

here is some pseudo-code which will populate a memory buffer of raw audio with a reasonable sample rate and bit depth which can be rendered into audio by any player ... its part of a proof of concept I wrote using OpenAL to do the audio rendering

```
hex_buffer gets defined and populated above

float freq = 100.f;
float incr_freq = 0.1f;

int seconds = 4;
unsigned sample_rate = 44100;
double my_pi = 3.14159;
size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate; // define buffer size

// allocate PCM audio buffer        
short * samples = malloc(sizeof(short) * buf_size);

printf("\nhere is freq %f\n", freq);
int i=0;
int index_hex = 0;
for(; i<buf_size; ++i) {

    samples[i] = 32760 * sin( (2.f * my_pi * freq)/sample_rate * i );

    /*
    freq += incr_freq; // comment out to synthesize pure sin wav

    if (100.0 > freq || freq > 5000.0) {

        incr_freq *= -1.0f;
    }
    */

    freq += convert_hex_to_float(hex_buffer(index_hex++))
}
```

above will get you into the ballpark ... here we iterate through your sequence of hex values (index_hex) ... commented out is where it merely increments variable freq by incr_freq you can replace incr_freq with a mapping of current hex to float using convert_hex_to_float

here is a helper function to translate a single hex char into integer

```
int hex2int(char ch) {

    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}
```

in below I am leaving out how we pluck out left and right hex character from your two char hex number

```
func convert_hex_to_float(given_hex) { // return float

    left_hex_char = pluck_out_first_hex_char(given_hex)
    right_hex_char = pluck_out_second_hex_char(given_hex)

    return (16.0 * hex2int(left_hex_char) + 1.0 * hex2int(right_hex_char))
}
```